# Using matplotlib, make date ticks not overlap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have dates for tick marks on my x-axis. How can I make them automatically not overlap?

There are a lot of S.O. questions and posts about setting the tick interval - but this won't work for me since the date range for my plot can vary from 1 week, up to 1 year.

When people have plots with highly variable ranges, what is the method to make the x-axis ticks automatically not overlap?

```
plt.plot(date_list, unique_list)
plt.ylabel('# Uniques per day')
```

[image]

Comment: The easiest workaround is to rotate the tick labels.  Have a look at `fig.autofmt_xdate()`, or you can manually set the rotation for the tick labels.

Answer (score 14):

You could rotate the xticks by 90 degrees (or any other value):

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

maybe you need to call `tight_layout()` if the ticks are then out of the frame

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough rep to comment, because I don't think the tip I am offering could solve this problem, but I had exactly the same issue.

My solution is to make the plot itself flatter, by 
`plt.figure(figsize = (20,6))`.

My reasoning is as such, there are only so many pixels and if changing the date format and rotation as suggested by others is not an option, maybe stretch the plot a bit?